# How to run a task on login of *any* user (or any member of a particular user group)

Tags: login, schedule, automatic

I have found many explanations of how to schedule a task to run on system start (which I am already doing by means of an entry starting with @reboot in /etc/crontab) or on login for a particular user ([this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-do-i-start-applications-automatically-on-login/514132#514132) seems to cover all the bases).
However, I would like to create a task to run when an AD domain user logs in to a Ubuntu client PC.  As a workaround, I would settle for a task which would run at login for any/every user on the Ubuntu PC (it would simply fail for local users).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this to work by creating a shell script in the directory /etc/profile.d containing:

```
if [[ " $(groups) " =~ ' domain users@my.domain.name ' ]]; then
# Whatever you want to do for all group members goes here.
fi
```

The script runs automatically on login as long as the file extension is .sh.
To prevent problems with output to a non-existent terminal, I append >/dev/null to the commands in the body of the if statement.